# Python execution process indepth

Tags: python

im beginning to learn the execution process of Python. I came across an article which attempts to explain the CPython virtual machine: https://tech.blog.aknin.name/2010/04/02/pythons-innards-introduction/

However i find his writings lacking depth. When the command **$ python -c 'print("Hello, world!")** is executed, am i correct to say that the python interpreter will be called, and the source code **print("Hello, world!")** will pass through series of lexing, parsing, compilation and finally execution by the virtual machine? Could you provide clarification on which functions are called and exactly what they accomplish?

Any resources which point to an indepth explanation is also welcomed!

> That said, let’s start with a bird’s eye overview of what happens when
> you do this: **$ python -c 'print("Hello, world!")'**. Python’s binary is
> executed, the standard C library initialization which pretty much any
> process does happens and then the main function starts executing (see
> its source, ./Modules/python.c: main, which soon calls
> ./Modules/main.c: Py_Main). After some mundane initialization stuff
> (parse arguments, see if environment variables should affect
> behaviour, assess the situation of the standard streams and act
> accordingly, etc), ./Python/pythonrun.c: Py_Initialize is called. In
> many ways, this function is what ‘builds’ and assembles together the
> pieces needed to run the CPython machine and makes ‘a process’ into ‘a
> process with a Python interpreter in it’. Among other things, it
> creates two very important Python data-structures: the interpreter
> state and thread state. It also creates the built-in module sys and
> the module which hosts all builtins. At a later post(s) we will cover
> all these in depth.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions?